# Adding controls at run time using perl win32::gui

Tags: perl

How to add a control in a window at run time using perl win32::GUI?
I have a button control in my window. I need to create a checkbox control in the same window, while I am clicking the button. 
I have written the code as mentioned in below, which is not working also.
Please give the correct way to proceed to adding controls at run time using perl Win32::GUI

```
use strict;
use Win32;
use Win32::GUI;

my $win=Win32::GUI::Window->new(
        -name => 'wino',
        -text => 'window',
        -left => 375,
        -top  => 400,
        -width =>380,
        -height =>260,
);
my $but=$win->AddButton(
      -text=>"Add Control",
      -onclick=>\&add_control,
);

 $win->Show();
 Win32::GUI::Dialog();

 sub add_control(){

   my $mchk=$win->AddCheckbox(
    -text=>"run_time_con",
    -pos=>[180,145],
   );

   $mchk->Show();

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't the code which adds the control, it's the fact that the button click event isn't wired up properly. See the [documentation](http://perl-win32-gui.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/docs.cgi?doc=userguide-concepts#events).

Try this instead:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Win32;
use Win32::GUI();

my $win=Win32::GUI::Window->new(
        -name => 'wino',
        -text => 'window',
        -left => 375,
        -top  => 400,
        -width =>380,
        -height =>260,
);

my $but=$win->AddButton(
      -name => "Button1",
      -text=>"Add Control"
);

$win->Show();
Win32::GUI::Dialog();

sub Button1_Click(){
   my $mchk=$win->AddCheckbox(
    -text=>"run_time_con",
    -pos=>[180,145],
   );

   $mchk->Show();
}
```

Comment: Yes, just now I have noticed that. Thanks... :-)